# Style Sheet to layout and SeekSlider?

Tags: qt, layout, qtstylesheets

I need some help here, I have two questions regarding Qt's style sheet customization

I know that I can set background image to a Widget but can I set a background image to a layout using Qt Style Sheets?
And can I customize the SeekSlider with Style Sheets?

---

I found out that I can customize a SeekSlider just like a QSlider. Now the layout remains.

---

I added the Layout to a Widget with setLayout and I use style sheet to that widget to put a background image .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layouts have no visual representation. They simply control the size and position of child widgets. You would set the style for the widget to which the layout is attached.